# Check if View (GUID) is displayed on the current ASPX page

Tags: javascript

Result of eXtreme Programming.. (and too early to drink wodka)

I am sure there is a one-liner to **check if a View is displayed on screen**

```
function webPartOnScreen(guid) {
    guid = guid.replace('{', '').replace('}', '').toLowerCase();
    var onscreen = false;
    Object.keys(_spWebPartComponents).forEach(function (id) {
        if (_spWebPartComponents[id].storageId === guid) onscreen = true;
    });
    return onscreen;
}

if webPartOnScreen( "{F841C9C5-7CB7-4105-A3EA-DD5B98C5E2E3}" ) console.warn('Hello View!');
```

### (from comments) By Anders Aune:

```
var webPartOnScreen= Object.keys(g_ctxDict).filter(function(v){
  return "{D3CA4CB5-58AC-44DA-BF0C-3009AEE2D1A1}" === g_ctxDict[v].view
}).length ? true : false;
```

Nice use of the filter function

Comment: Are you looking for a built in function, or just less verbose code? I haven't seen any built in function, the code you use looks like something I have done before with g_ctxDict, something like this: `var webPartOnScreen= Object.keys(g_ctxDict).filter(function(v,i){return "{D3CA4CB5-58AC-44DA-BF0C-3009AEE2D1A1}" === g_ctxDict[v].view}).length ? true : false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built in function named `GetCtxFromView` defined in `INPLVIEW.js`:

```
function GetCtxFromView(viewGuid) {
    var myCtx = null;

    for (var ctxId in g_ctxDict) {
        var ctxT = g_ctxDict[ctxId];

        if (ctxT.view == viewGuid) {
            myCtx = ctxT;
            break;
        }
    }
    return myCtx;
}
```

Could be used like this:

```
var webPartOnScreen = GetCtxFromView("{74072373-B250-483E-A2BF-67E95291A419}") ? true : false
```

Comment: Another 6 lines of code gone... You are better then (the minifier) uglifyJS!